# Failed to start elasticsearch due to a fatal signal received by control process (code=killed, signal=9/KILL)

Tags: elasticsearch

When I try to start Elasticsearch, there's an error saying
"Job for Elasticsearch.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process.
See `systemctl status elasticsearch.service` and `journalctl -xe" for details`.
When I check Elasticsearch status. I got

```log
$ systemctl status elasticsearch.service
  elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: signal) since Tue 2021-05-11 18:17:21 IST; 3min 48s ago
       Docs: https://www.elastic.co
    Process: 25730 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/systemd-entrypoint -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet (code=killed, s>
   Main PID: 25730 (code=killed, signal=KILL)

May 11 18:17:18  systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
May 11 18:17:21  systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
May 11 18:17:21  systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
May 11 18:17:21  systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
```

And for `journalctl -xe`

```log
May 11 18:20:20  dbus-daemon[530]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.f>
May 11 18:20:20  systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
-- A start job for unit systemd-hostnamed.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 6553.
May 11 18:20:20  dbus-daemon[530]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
May 11 18:20:20  systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
-- Subject: A start job for unit systemd-hostnamed.service has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit systemd-hostnamed.service has finished successfully.
-- 
-- The unit UNIT has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
May 11 18:20:50  systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit systemd-hostnamed.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
```

I have kept an account on heap memory (ie -Xms and -Xmx) and TimeoutStartSec but its about other process killing it.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure the user which you are using to run the elasticsearch process has write access to the filesystem where the elasticsearch process is writing.

Comment: Hey thanks for reply! I was able to run it. Previously i tried to install using deb package of the same and seems like there was a conflict even after uninstalling. It did fine after restart

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, Elasticsearch may not start, or get killed just after starting if your system is low on or out of memory.

I was facing a similar issue, and restarting my computer fixed the issue.